# dbpedia SPARQL book search query

Tags: dbpedia

I am trying to retrieve the titles of books for the precededBy and followedBy attributes of dbpedia using the sparql search. 
Eg. http://dbpedia.org/page/Harry_Potter_and_the_Goblet_of_Fire - A query that will return the preceding and following book titles. So If I put in the book title 'Chamber of Secrets' I would get the books before and after that returned.

Ive tried watching a couple videos about sparql and looked through the examples here https://km.aifb.kit.edu/projects/spartiqulator/examples.htm but can't seem to produce a working query.

I have tried the following but it produces syntax errors. I am not certain how to link the attributes I am trying to filter in the correct way, eg the rdf: and dbp etc.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX res:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>


SELECT DISTINCT ?uri  
WHERE {
    ?uri rdf:type dbo:Book .
    ?uri dbp:precededBy res:'Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets' .

}
```

The following runs but with no results.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX res:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>


SELECT DISTINCT ?uri  
WHERE {
    ?uri rdf:type dbo:Book .
    ?uri dbp:followedBy 'Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix' .

}
```

Comment: Please sho us, what you have already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know both precededBy and followedBy for Chamber of Secrets, you can use this query:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  dbr:Harry_Potter_and_the_Chamber_of_Secrets
    dbp:precededBy ?precededBy;
    dbp:followedBy ?followedBy.
}
```

Notice how the name if formatted just like in Wikipedia URL, with underscores instead of spaces.

Also note that if a book does not have one of the two, this will return nothing. You can use `OPTIONAL` to work around that.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was after.